# how do i whitelist my domain for enabling autofill with linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api, autofill

My client has added me in campaign manager account, I need to whitelist my domain to get the autoFill working on my website, right now its throwing CORS warning. And as per LinkedIn documentation

'Send your LinkedIn representative a list of domains and subdomains where you will be placing the AutoFill code to whitelist your domains. Please include "https" and "www" in your domain and subdomain URLs.'

How should I set this up and where should I set this up?

Answer (score 1):

Please send your domains to linkedin account manager and they will do whitelist.

Please go through the [URL](https://www.linkedin.com/help/lms/answer/65513?query=insight%20tag) for more information on how to do whitelist.

also, check this AutoFill Setup [Guide](https://www.linkedin.com/help/lms/answer/65688)